# Prove that this expression is equal to $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, recreational-mathematics

Today, on the auspicious $\pi$ day, I saw on a local chat group $$\pi=4\phi^2\left(\phi^2+2\sqrt{\phi}\right)\left(\int_{\ 0}^{\ \infty\ }e^{x^2}\frac{\ \sin\left(x^2\right)\ }{x^2}dx\right)^2$$ I wonder how one can prove this.

My first thoughts were to evaluate the term involving the golden ratio. I calculated it approximately with the help of wolframaplha but you see that I can't prove it with mathematical methods. And for the integral I've no idea as I don't know how to solve improper integrals.

This is what I saw [image]

Edit: I confirmed this query with the Original poster. Indeed it should be $e^{{-x}^2}.$ Surprised that wolfram got it wrong...

Comment: The integral is divergent.

Comment: @AnneBauval wolframaplha says the opposite

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad: You must have meant $e^{-x^2}$ under the integral. Unless this is fixed, you gonna get "dry answers" like above (Wolfy has no voice here). And for context... where is this problem from?

Comment: @metamorphy The Wolfram response does not seem to be a "fluke" or anything, it is apparently convergent: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+e%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D+sin%28x%5E2%29+%2F+x%5E2dx

Comment: The problem I'm seeing is moreso that, with the value of the integral given by Wolfram (around 1.94), the right hand side is going to exceed $\pi$ by quite a lot. So, even if the integral is convergent instead of divergent like it is claimed above, it might be the case that it is $e^{-x^2}$ instead of $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: What does that $\phi$ stand for?

Comment: Should I attach the image of this question $?$

Comment: @Dominique golden ratio

Comment: Can you check if you typed in the problem correctly? [This is what I'm seeing](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4%28golden+ratio%29%5E2+%28%28golden+ratio%29%5E2+%2B+2sqrt%28golden+ratio%29%29%28integral+e%5E%28x%5E2%29sin%28x%5E2%29%2Fx%5E2+from+0+to+infty%29%5E2).

Comment: Hmm even with $e^{-x^2}$ it's [over 35...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4%28golden+ratio%29%5E2+%28%28golden+ratio%29%5E2+%2B+2sqrt%28golden+ratio%29%29%28integral+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29sin%28x%5E2%29%2Fx%5E2+from+0+to+infty%29%5E2)

Comment: We can rigorously prove that the integral diverges as an improper Riemann integral. *Mathematica 13*, which is another product of Wolfram, can also correctly confirm that the integral diverges. Finally, for $a>0$, we have $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2(a + \sqrt{a^2+1})}},$$ but neither plugging $a=1$ nor the *unallowed* choice $a=-1$ gives the proposed value $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\phi(\sqrt{\phi}+1)}$. (This value is achieved with the choice $a\approx13.496$.)

Comment: Wolfram alpha always uses previous version of Mathematica. Only 13 version got normal recognition of all kind of Integrals divergence.

Comment: Can anyone pls give the link of mathematics 13

Comment: Did whoever posted this say where they got it?

Comment: @eyeballfrog no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in my first comment above, the integral is divergent (so: [wolframaplha is wrong](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+0+to+infinity+e%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D+sin%28x%5E2%29+%2F+x%5E2dx)). Indeed, let $a_k:=\frac\pi2+2k\pi$ with $\Bbb N\ni k\to+\infty$ then
$$\int_{\sqrt{a_k-\frac\pi4}}^{\sqrt{a_k+\frac\pi4}}e^{x^2}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}dx=\frac12\int_{a_k-\frac\pi4}^{a_k+\frac\pi4}e^y\frac{\sin y}{y^{3/2}}dy
$$
$$\ge\frac{e^{a_k-\frac\pi4}}{2\sqrt2(a_k+\frac\pi4)^{3/2}}\to+\infty$$

Comment: Very rarely (exactly once in about a dozen tries for me), refreshing these WA results will correctly display a message saying "(integral does not converge)" but right below the, er, exact value...

Comment: This answer makes me wonder what, exactly, WolframAlpha is computing here. Some kind of regularization of the divergent integral?

Comment: Maybe it is somethung like, Sum does, but NSum does not check for convergence apart from simplest test: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/185209/82985

Answer (score 1):

You are doing very tricky things here, like $\phi^2 + 2\sqrt{\phi}$.
Let's have a look at this:

As $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$, we can say that:

$$\phi^2 + 2\sqrt{\phi}$$
$$ = \phi + 2\sqrt{\phi} + 1$$
$$ = (\sqrt{\phi} + 1)^2$$

In top of that, as mentioned in some comments, you're not dealing with $e^{x^2}$, but with $e^{-x^2}$, so you need to prove:

$$\int_{\ 0}^{\ \infty\ }e^{-x^2}\frac{\ \sin\left(x^2\right)\ }{x^2}dx = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \phi \cdot (\sqrt{\phi} + 1)}$$

In case you doubt about the replacement of $e^{x^2}$ by $e^{-x^2}$:

This are the graphs of both (as long as Geogebra does not go nuts on the exponential numbers :-) ):

[image]

That should give you something to start with :-)

Comment: Why is it $e^{-x^2}$ and not $e^{x^2}$?

Comment: @Accelerator: when you use $e^{x^2}$, you get a divergent integral.

Comment: How does one prove that then? Not like WolframAlpha is always 100%, but apparently according to it, the integral converges.

Comment: @Accelerator: sometimes an image says more than a thousand words :-)

Comment: I find it not obvious from the yellow curve that the integral is divergent.

Comment: @AnneBauval: why not? The function is going up and down, up to more than exponential heights. How can this not be divergent?

Comment: The heigths are not sufficient, the widths matter.

Comment: @Are you saying that you know a function, going up and down in a more than exponential way, and still has a convergent integral?

Comment: Although I complete agree with you that the integral diverges, the fact that the integrand diverges as $x\to\infty$ alone is not enough to conclude divergence. For example, the improper integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^x\sin(e^{2x})\,\mathrm{d}x$$ *converges* conditionally. We need a more quantitative argument such as in Anne Bauval's answer.

Comment: Another problem with this answer is that you're claiming $\int_{\ 0}^{\ \infty\ }e^{-x^2}\frac{\ \sin\left(x^2\right)\ }{x^2}dx = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \phi \cdot (\sqrt{\phi} + 1)}$, but I [approximated both expressions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wbhuxxqz8q) up to many digits, and they certainly don't seem equal at all.

Comment: @SangchulLee: Oh, I'm sorry. Now I see: your integral converges because the speed at which the numbers grow larger is slower than the speed at which the widths get narrower, causing a converging integral. This, however, is not the case of our integral here. (But you're right, I must be more careful)

Comment: Yes, whence my "The heigths are not sufficient, the widths matter," I thank @SangchulLee for sparing me the effort of constructing an explicit example answering your "Are you saying that you know a function..." doubtful reply.

Comment: @Accelerator: why is that? Did I make a mistake or is the original (even with $e^{-x^2}$ wrong to start with?

Comment: @AnneBauval: Indeed. Thanks to Sangchul's remark I understand that now.

Comment: We all know at this point the original post is wrong no matter what, but now I know that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x^{2}}\sin\left(x^{2}\right)}{x^{2}}dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2+2\sqrt{2}}}$ after reading Sangchul's comment, and your post says the integral equals something else.

Comment: @Accelerator: Great! So you do know the answer of the question. Can you write your own answer? I'd like to see how you get this result.

Comment: I don't know how to derive that result off the top of my head. I just got it from that comment I mentioned. Even if I did know, I wouldn't feel like posting an answer because the original post has $e^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(x^2\right)}{x^2}\,dx=\Im\int\frac{e^{-(1-i) x^2}}{x^2} \,dx=\frac 12 \Im\int \frac{e^{-(1-i) t}}{ t^{3/2}}\,dt$$
One integration by parts leads to an incomplete gamma function and using the bounds
$$I=\int\frac{e^{-x^2} \sin \left(x^2\right)}{x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) \pi }\quad \implies\quad I^2=\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}  \pi$$

No way to get it.

Answer (score 0):

For $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re z>0$ we have $$\int_0^\infty e^{-zt^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2\sqrt{z}}\implies\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-zt^2}}{t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi z}.$$ This gives, as an example, $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\frac{\sin x^2}{x^2}\,dx=\Im\sqrt{\pi(1+i)}=\sqrt{\frac\pi2(\sqrt2-1)}.$$